# Recurrence Relation of Order 2. particular solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am stuck on the following question:
$$g(n+2)+2g(n+1)+2g(n)=25n$$

Starting conditions: $$g(0)=0, g(1)=1$$

I have worked out the homogenous Solotion to be $$g(n)^h=C1 * (-1+i)^n+C2*(-1-i)^n$$
Because of $f(n)=25n$ i have tried the approach of $f{\check{}}(n)=An$
$$ A(n+2)+2A(n+1)+2An=25n$$
This simplifies to:
$$ A(5n+4)= 25n$$
How should I continue or what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should assume $f(n) = an + b$ You are running into trouble by forgetting that constant term.

Then

$$ a(5n + 4) + 5b = 25n $$

So: $4a + 5b = 0$ and $5a = 25$. So we get that $a = 5$ and $b = -4$

---

The general problem is

$$ g(n+2) + 2g(n+1) + 2g(n) = 25n$$

Assuming $g(n) = an + b$  then we have

$$ an + 2a + b + 2an + 2a + 2b + 2an + 2b = 25n$$

Therefore

$$(a + 2a + 2a) = 25 $$
$$2a + b + 2a + 2b + 2b = 0 $$

This can then be solved as a system of two linear equations in two unkowns.

$$ 5a = 25  \\ 4a + 5b = 0 $$

Giving $a=5$ and $b=-4$

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. When do I need to include the constant term? Can you elaborate?

Comment: short version: you should always include it,  if you dont then it just doesn't work as you noticed.

Comment: long version: we are dealing with polynomials here that is expressions of the form $a_0 n^0 + a_1 n^1 + a_2 n^2 + ... $. So if you include the linear terms $a_1 n^1 = an$ then it should feel wrong to forget that the constant term $a_0 n^0 = a_0 * 1 = b$ exists

Comment: accurate version: If you have a recurrence of the form $c_0 g(n+s_0) + c_1 g(n+s_1) + .... c_n g(n+s_n)= cn$ and $c_0s_0 + c_1s_1 + .... c_ns_n = 0$ then you don't need the constant term. If you include it, it will just come out to $b=0$

Comment: Now that trick I gave works, but i would forget the trick if i was you and just always assume there are constant terms unless you are doing something advanced enough that not-having-a-constant-term is important.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, you helped me a lot in understanding this problem.

Comment: Hey I noticed you just unaccepted this answer. Was something wrong or missing?